# Mysql query for get repeated customers list

Tags: mysql, select

I have a two tables `oc_order` and `oc_customer`. I want to get customers who order more than once.

This is sample:

**oc_order:**

```
order_id | cus_id | cus_name
-------------------------------
1        | 1      | Kumar
2        | 2      | Vimal
3        | 1      | Kumar
4        | 3      | Ramesh
```

**oc_customer**

```
  cus_id   | cus_name |  cus_address
    -----------------------------------
    1        | Kumar    |  Chennai
    2        | Vimal    |  Coimbatore
    3        | Ramesh   |  Selam
    4        | Deepan   |  Chennai
    5        | Ashok    |  Coimbatore
```

> For the above example i want to select only repeated order customer details only.

I mean now select only `cus_id`- 1 details, because customer one order more then one time.

This is the query am used

```
SELECT * 
FROM oc_order o 
LEFT JOIN oc_customer oc ON (o.customer_id = oc.customer_id) 
WHERE  (SELECT * 
        FROM oc_order 
        WHERE customer_id=o.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM oc_customer c
JOIN oc_order o ON c.cus_id = o.cus_id 
GROUP BY c.cus_id
HAVING COUNT(o.order_id) > 1
```

Comment: Akina Thanks for your query please wait let me check

Comment: Thanks for your code Its working. if you like this question please upvote this querstion